# Read input field files when seperate button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

With the following input field, the user submits one or multiple HTML files.

```
<input type="file" id="inputfield" accept="text/html" multiple/>
<div id="get-files">Get Files</div>
```

When `get-files` is clicked, how can I get the content of each file on the input field and mess with each file content using the fileReader API?

I tried the following but receive no errors or content.

```
$("#get-files").on("click", function() { getFilesContent(); });
function getFilesContent() {
    var pages = $("#inputfield")[0].files;
    // get files data
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function() {
            return function(e) {
                console.log($("#inputfield")[0].result);
            }
        });
        reader.readAsText(pages[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
function getFilesContent() {
    var pages = $("#inputfield")[0].files;    
    for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            console.log(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsText(pages[i]);
    }
}
```

`reader.result` contains your HTML data.